Finding minimum required number of refuels while traversing between towns, if we can refuel at each town up to constant L
I try to solve this problem: AtCoder E - Travel By Car

Firstly I tried to solve it using two 2D arrays: parents, distances where parents[i][j] means what was the intermediate node (Floyd Warshall algorithm) between i and j town that led us to our the best current distance[i][j] (shortest distance between town i and j). Then while processing queries I was reconstructing the path from town s to t using parents array, and while this process I was checking whether edge between node u and v (contained in path) can be traversed without refuelling, incremented needed number of total refuels etc.
I thought it will work because if we have shortest path then we will also use the minimum number of fuels. Why? Because if some edge requires much fuel, then others (contained in shortest path) will require much less, so we will end up with optimal solution. Now I know this approach doesn't work, because the shortest path can contains edges that aren't traversable on single fuel so the path won't be traversable at all, but optimal one may still exist. Additionaly, basing on test case output, it doesn't work for other reasons which I don't even see.
So I started reading Editorial

That's the code from it:
#define inf 1e9

vector<int> travelByCar(int n, int l, vector<vector<int>>edges, vector<vector<int>> queries)
{
    vector<vector<int>>dis(n + 1, vector<int>(n + 1, inf)), fuel(n + 1, vector<int>(n + 1, inf));
    int x, y, val;
    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++)
    {
        x = edges[i][0], y = edges[i][1], val = edges[i][2];
        x--;
        y--;
        dis[x][x] = 0;
        dis[y][y] = 0;
        fuel[x][x] = 0;
        fuel[y][y] = 0;
        dis[x][y] = val;
        dis[y][x] = val;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                if (dis[j][k] > dis[j][i] + dis[i][k])
                {
                    dis[j][k] = dis[j][i] + dis[i][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (dis[i][j] <= l)
            {
                fuel[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
// Can't understand this part
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                if (fuel[j][k] > fuel[j][i] + fuel[i][k])
                {
                    fuel[j][k] = fuel[j][i] + fuel[i][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    vector<int> ans;
    for (int i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++)
    {
        x = queries[i][0], y = queries[i][1];
        x--;
        y--;
        if (fuel[x][y] == inf)
        {
            ans.push_back(-1);
        }
        else {
            ans.push_back(fuel[x][y] - 1);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

As commented, I can't understand part with Floyd Warshall on fuel vector. Firstly, fuel[i][j] = 1 if the dist[i][j] <= l (l is the max fuel tank capacity).
Let's say we have fuel[i][k] + fuel[k][j]. Assume they both have value equal to 1, so the sum is 2. But may there is option to travel from i to j via k using only one fuel? When I have path fuel[i][k] that requries 1 fuel, and fuel[k][j], why is it assumed that one fuel won't be enough for traversing both of them? If the 1 fuel is required for traversing some path, it doesn't mean that it is too little for traversing one more path (which will be combined with the first one).
What don't I understand? Why it works?

Counterexample to "shortest path is best". Say L==20, and there are two ways to get from A to B: one requires two hops of length 19 each, the other three hops of length 11 each. The first path is length 38 but requires refueling once. The second path is lenth 33 but requires refueling twice.

"But may there is option to travel from i to j via k using only one fuel?" If there exists any path, through any towns, from i to j of length less than L, then by construction fuel[i][j] == 1. The piece if (dis[i][j] <= l) { fuel[i][j] = 1; } does that.

I would use Yen's algorithm to solve this. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm )

Apply Yen's algorithm to obtain a list of all the paths between si and ti sorted into increasing length
Loop P over paths in increasing length

SET ok = true
LOOP R over roads in P

IF R is longer than L

SET ok = false
BREAK from LOOP R




ENDLOOP R
IF OK = true

OUTPUT P
STOP


ENDLOOP P
OUTPUT -1




Your algorithm finds shortest passable path; not necessarily path requiring the least number of refuels. It should be easy to adapt; finding the minimum number of refuels along a given path is itself a pretty simple dynamic programming problem.

The shortest path is the path with the least total road length => the least amount of fuel => the least number of refuels.

See my comment to the original question. "Least road length" doesn't imply "least number of refuels" because you can't refuel in the middle of the road whenever you run out of fuel.
